# Finding the graphics card device ID without drivers installed

Tags: windows, hardware

I need to create an automated process in which a script detects the graphics card type on first boot, then installs the appropriate drivers, which will be included in the image, before performing the next steps. The target platform is Win XP Pro.

I came across some [WMI](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/d00cd10a-7638-4063-8781-1bca5051d1c2) code which can get hardware information but since it uses a PNPSignedDriver class I would presume that it requires drivers to be installed before it can detect the device.

I can't use devcon, as it isn't redistributable. Am I right in assuming that WMI cannot help me here, and if so what are my other options?

Thanks,

Bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMI does seem to be the way to do this, as found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/d6420012-e432-4964-8506-6f6b65e5a451). I will confirm after testing.

EDIT - Not sure if this is possible, WMI can only get the name of the display adapter not the device ID of the card, and before the drivers are installed this is something generic like "Video Controller (VGA)". I will update this page if I find a way.